# Django urls.reverse with argument

Tags: django, url, testing, reverse

Stuck on this for a while:

in Django pytest I am trying to do

```
req = RequestFactory().get(reverse('app_name:app_view_name'))
```

But I require the url to have '/[number]' at the end so that UpdateView will recognise the number and display appropriate form from model.

In the browser the links and form submission all work fine, but I am unable to use reverse() in testing. I have tried:

```
req = RequestFactory().get(reverse('app_name:app_view_name', args=[1]))
```

and

```
req = RequestFactory().get(reverse('app_name:app_view_name'), kwargs=['pk'=1])
```

but none of these work. I am simply trying to build the url with '/1' added at the end.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `kwargs` expects a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It expects a [*dictionary*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), like you can find in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.get):

```
RequestFactory().get(reverse('app_name:app_view_name'),
                     {'pk': 1})
```